# Azure SCIM custom attribute - email domain as a passed attribute

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, scim, scim2

In my Azure SCIM configuration I want to have the email domain as one of the attributes sent to the receiving app.  The receiving app already has the filter built and can then assign rights to the user in provisioning based on email but I cannot figure out how to send just the '@domainname.com' to it. I am trying to avoid using extension attributes since those would need manual intervention.  I would like to somehow take the information from the email field from the user properties.

I have gone through the custom expression builder and none of the given operators seem to fit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/functions-for-customizing-application-data for reference

Two options that I can see..

#1 is the replace function - the userPrincipalName example 4 in the documentation for replace is pretty similar to what you're trying to do, but pulls the left side of the email address rather than the right.

I haven't tested it, but I think something like

> (?(.)*@<emailDomain>)

rather than the given example of

> (?<Suffix>@(.)*)

would work. Definitely test before using in production as I'm a bit rusty on my regex :)

You also may be able to use a nested combination of Split and Item functions - Split([mail],@) with bob@domain.com should return an array of "Bob" "domain.com" - so if you then wrap that, then using Item(Split([mail],@),2) I think you'd get the domain returned as it would be index 2? Again.. no guarantees this is syntactically correct, but I think it's a/the right path.